# how do I undo a checkin in bitkeeper that isn't part of a changeset?

Tags: version-control, undo, bitkeeper

I have a file in a project that is in a bitkeeper repository.  I checked in a file but I haven't committed the change to create a changeset.  How can I undo the checkin?

If I had a changeset I could undo the commit with:

```
bk undo -r<rev>
```

But in this case I can't commit and undo the changeset because I have other checked-in files that I don't want to touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can undo a checkin outside of a commit using `bk stripdel`:

```
bk stripdel -r<rev> filename
```

For instance, checking in with this:

```
nfellman@xyz> bk ci a.c 
End comments with "." by itself or a blank line.
a.c 1.242>>  a
a.c@1.242>>  b
a.c@1.242>>  .
a.c revision 1.242: +0 -4 = 6731
a.c 1.242 -> 1.243
```

And then undoing the checkin with this:

```
nfellman@xyz> bk stripdel -r1.242 a.c
stripdel: removed 1 deltas from a.c
```

Answer (score 2):

Slight improvement on the answer...

You can use -r+ to refer to the top revision.  So the stripdel
becomes:

```
bk stripdel -r+ a.c
```